# What localization code should you use in Xcode for the "Mexican Spanish" locale

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

In iTunes connect, you can submit Spanish and Mexican Spanish localizations. I'm using the "spa" locale for Spain (Spanish), but "spm" doesn't work for Mexico in the simulator.

Ideally I think I'd like to use a locale code that would work for all latin american countries Spanish, as I think they prefer the Mexican variant.

What is the correct code to use?

Comment: They will prefer it. To Spanish speakers of the Americas, spanish-spanish sounds and reads something like a prissy, lisping, upper-class English accent would sound to english speaking North Americans.

Comment: Mexican Spanish is considered to be the most accent-neutral variant. So indeed they will prefer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post in the Apple forums, only one version of Spanish is allowed. However they do allow British English (en_GB) and Portuguese for Portugal (pt_PT).

https://devforums.apple.com/message/253355

Answer (score 5):

`es-MX`.  For any Spanish variant, use `es`.  If you want to specifically refer to Castilian Spanish (for example), use `es-ES`.  I'm not sure where the official list of these codes is, but it's got to be around somewhere (if you find it, leave a comment w/ the link!).

Comment: Alas, that's not working for me. After making sure I clean and rebuild and restarting the simulator each time, only the strings in es are read. Neither es-MX or es-ES are respected by the simulator...